# Several Issues regarding the usage of UML in SPA Angular

Tags: mysql, uml, angular-ui-router, restangular, model-driven-development

While we are waiting for the next upcoming version of javascript, that is ECMAScript 6 codename Harmony, we are enforced to use object-based/functional-based javascript. Currently there are no class construct, interface, inheritance, means for information hiding, and so on. But I won't argue about its usefulness, I just wondering about the usage of UML constructs in complete Single Page Application framework such as AngularJS.

1. Is UML only appropriate for ECMAScript 6 Harmony?
2. It is said that when we use mongoDB we are no longer need ORM
   anymore because the output is already object, then now Oracle has
   provided [HTTP Plugin](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2014/mysql-5-7-http-plugin-mysql/) that enable MySQL to provide RESTful CRUD API
   and has JSON as its output. The question is, when I creates Class
   Diagram, I can convert it to JPA entity class, than is it still
   useful when I use Restangular-->MySQL or just nice to have?
3. In Doug Rosenberg & Matt Stephens' book Use Case Driven Object
   Modeling with UML, they use one boundary lifeline for each page and
   entity lifeline for each domain model that are involved within his
   sequence diagram, so when I use Angular-UI's UI-Router, then what is
   it count to be boundary lifeline? is it each state? then I guess the
   control lifeline is my angular's registered controller, and entity
   lifeline for my javascript object that I pass to each Restangular's
   post/put/delete method, aren't they?
4. I think Restangular is a kind of Data Access Object, isn't it?
5. Is this kind of Model Driven Development not appropriate for
   AngularJS at all, if so then what it is that appropriate?

code example for accesing mysql directly from restangular:

```
Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization':'Basic '+btoa("basic_auth_user:basic_auth_passwd")});
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/crud/mydatabase/');

myModule.controller('salesmanController',
function($scope, Restangular){
var salesmanDAO = Restangular.all('salesmanTable');
$scope.allSalesman = salesmanDAO.getList().$object;


$scope.insertSalesman = function(){
    var newSalesman = {firstName: $scope.newSalesman.firstName, lastName: $scope.newSalesman.lastName, city: $scope.newnewSalesman.city};
    salesmanDAO.post(newSalesman)
    .then(
        function(newObject){
            $scope.allSalesman = salesmanDAO.getList().$object;
        },
        function error(reason){
            console.log("the reason: ", reason)
        }
    );
    $scope.newSalesman.firstName = '';
    $scope.newSalesman.lastName = '';
    $scope.newSalesman.city = '';
}
```

Comment: As long as you can see the world (and the world of the being you built from code atoms) through the glasses of [Object Oriented Paradigm (OOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) then using the Unified Modeling Language (UML) is appropriate. BTW: the waiting for the prophet phase can be shortened by using [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/). ECMA 6 compatibility is among it's language design goals

Comment: I think it is always important to use uml as strictly as necessary to describe your design and no stricter. Dont convolute your diagram because you are trying to make it fit into a strict uml spec. Additionally, when describing use cases in terms of ui-router, don't force yourself to set hard and fast rules. Sometimes diagramming a state will be useful and other times crossing boundaries will be useful. To sum things up, its more important that your diagrams describe your design then that they are 100% strict. That said, I agree it would be nice if there were some idiomatic js patterns

Comment: when I search for "view state sequence diagram" in googe books, I found [this](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=BFlF1TQQ26gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=View+States+Sequence+Diagram&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rwGPVIm-E8-zuATm7IAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sequence%20diagram&f=false), it said that Adobe Flex also has a notion of states, I think ui-router and adobe flex's state have something in common, but the sequence diagram in that page the author doesn't mention anything about state just a form, as @benschwartz [said](http://goo.gl/dYL5nw): "A sequence diagram may not intuitively map to a single state."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is UML only appropriate for ECMAScript 6 Harmony?

No, UML (class diagrams and sequence/activity diagrams), can always be used for making IT-independent conceptual (information and process) models as well as platform-independent (information and process) design models. This is independent of any programming language. So these models can (and should) be used, no matter if you are using Java, C# or JavaScript for your implementation.

It's another question which code patterns can be used for implementing a class concept in JavaScript. Here, we basically have two choices, as discussed in [this section](http://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/webeng/JsFrontendApp/complete-tutorial.html#sectDefClass) of my book [Engineering Frontend Web Apps with Plain JavaScript](http://web-engineering.info/JsFrontendApp-Book),

1. The classical **constructor-based** class pattern recommended by Mozilla on their MDN website. The new ECMAScript 6 `class` construct is just syntactic sugar for this constructor-based pattern.
2. In the form of a *factory* object that uses the predefined `Object.create` method for creating new instances of a class. In this **factory-based** approach, which has been recommended by Eric Elliott, the prototype-based inheritance mechanism is replaced by another mechanism.  Elliott argues that factory-based classes are a viable alternative to constructor-based classes in JavaScript.

Notice, however, that in AngularJS, there is no real concept of a ***model class***, but you can certainly use your own approach.

> It is said that when we use mongoDB we are no longer need ORM anymore because the output is already object

This is plain wrong. A kind of ORM (or maybe better ***object-to-storage mapping***) is always needed, e.g., for mapping

1. internal object references (representing associations) to ID references with some form of referential integrity,
2. class hierarchies to certain storage structures (e.g. a single table or object store with optional attributes)

> Is this kind of Model Driven Development not appropriate for AngularJS

The approach of Model-Driven Development can be used for any kind of target platform, including AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks @gwag for your explanation and pointing your book, it really shade the light on. I cited the mongodb orm from [here](http://www.mongodb.com/what-is-mongodb). I think I have difficulty in articulating my 2nd question, but the question that answered by blog posting from amber kaplan is really what I meant, [how complicated will it be to model our data-especially in AngularJS](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2014/07/angularjs-data-models-http-vs-resource-vs-restangular/) it has nothing to do with mysql, nor uml, Restangular is great for MySQL REST endpoints when it is well-structured